# Uploading files using arrays

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload

```
$file_path = "files/";
$file_temps = array("temp_1_file.txt", "temp_2_file.txt");
$file_names = array("new_file.txt", "temp_1_file.txt");

foreach($file_temps as $file_temp){
    foreach($file_names as $file_name){
        move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path."/".$file_name);
        break;
    }<br>
}
<br>
```

This only uploads one file, i dont understand. Please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you use `break` inside the second `foreach`. You may use something like:

```
$files = array(
  "temp_1_file.txt" => "files/new_file.txt",
  "temp_2_file.txt" => "files/temp_1_file.txt"
);

foreach($files as $fileTemp => $fileName){
    move_uploaded_file($fileTemp, $fileName);
}
```

**or** if you want to use 2 arrays:

```
$filePath = 'files/';
$fileTemps = array("temp_1_file.txt", "temp_2_file.txt");
$fileNames = array("new_file.txt", "temp_1_file.txt");

foreach($fileTemps as $key => $fileTemp){
    move_uploaded_file($fileTemp, $filePath . $fileNames[$key]);
}
```